# What does the plus sign do in this example?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given these two variables:

```
 Row = [Row(name='a', age=12, gender='man', score='123'), Row(name='b', age=23, gender='woman', score='110'), Row(name='c', age=120, gender='man', score='60')]
```

and

```
headers = ('name', 'age', 'gender', 'score')
```

When i loop through them to get the max item in each row with a plus sign i get the below:

```
for i in range(4):

    print(max([str(x[i]) for x in Row]+[headers[i]]))

...
name
age
woman
score
```

however when i replace the plus sign with a comma i get the below:

```
for i in range(4):

    print(max([str(x[i]) for x in Row],[headers[i]]))

...
['name']
['age']
['man', 'woman', 'man']
['score']
```

So, basically my question is, what does the plus sign do? normally i would call the max function with commas separating the iterables, like this `max(list1, list2)` but in this example `max` function is being called like this `max(list1+list2)`

Comment: It concatenates lists

Comment: I would have assumed a clean dupe for this, but they all seem to compare with `append`/`extend`, which isn't really what the OP was asking :/

Comment: In first example `[str(x[i]) for x in Row]+[headers[i]]` and you get an array of two strings so max(['a', 'b']) return string. In second example: max(['a'], ['b']) that returns array.

Comment: Don't use the same variable `Row` to hold the list as the name of the class. That effectively undefines the class.

Answer (score 2):

it adds the lists together
e.g.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = ['frog', 'dog']
print(list1 + list2)
```

#### Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 'frog', 'dog']
```

Answer (score 1):

It concatenates lists, which is to say it joins two lists together into one big list:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> c = a+b
>>> print(c)
[1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

If you have a `print` statement followed by items separated by commas, then it will just print those items, separated by whitespace.

```
>>> print(a,b)
[1, 2, 3] ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

When you call `max(list1, list2)`, this means, "Look at the two items, `list1` and `list2`, and return the one with the 'largest' value."  When you call `max(list1+list2)`, this means, "Combine `list1` and `list2` into one big list, then pick the 'largest' item from that combined list."  I put the word 'largest' in quotes here because `max()` works against non-numeric items too.

```
>>> d = [7, 8, 9]
>>> e = [0, 75, 21]
>>> print(max(d,e))
[7, 8, 9]
>>> print(max(d+e))
75
```

The reason the first one returns `[7, 8, 9]` is because Python considers this to be "larger" than `[0, 75, 21]`.  That's because when comparing two lists, Python checks it lexiconographically. 7 is greater than 0, so:

```
>>> d > e
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It joins the two lists together into one big list.

```
# The two different lists
letters = ['a','b','c']
numbers = [1,2,3]

# The plus sign
print(letter + number)

# Your result
['a','b','c',1,2,3]
```